# Why didn't the Chaos gods kill all of the Primarchs when the had the chance?

Tags: warhammer-40k

When the Chaos gods gain access to the laboratory where the Emporer is creating the [Primarchs](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/k0LuTy6BhJc/maxresdefault.jpg), they pull them into the warp and scatter them throughout the galaxy.

They drop each Primarch on a planet / moon / asteroid.

Why didn't they just fire them all into a star and destroy the Emporer's greatest creations when they had the chance?

Is it ever specifically explained?

Answer (score 6):

As most things in the 40k setting, it is left to the reader's interpretation; there is nothing specific out there.

The closest we get to an explanation is in *The First Heretic*, in which

> you learn that some Word Bearers, lead by a demon, travel to the time and place of birth of the primarchs, and destroy the machine monitoring them. Where they ended up was then an accident, not a plotted course.

Then again, they are *Chaos* gods: why destroy the primarchs when you can have them growing up so different they can't relate to each other anymore?

Comment: They might not have been best friends but they were still a united force. Had Horus not turned to Chaos, _and he very nearly didn't_, Chaos would have never taken hold as it did. Plus I'd have to assume that regular old Space Marines would be easier to corrupt than Primarchs so wiping them out at the start makes sense to me.

Comment: I would further speculate that the Chaos gods needed a Primarch (or Primarchs plural) to stop the Emperor.  Only a Primarch would be powerful enough to foil the Great Crusade.

Comment: @Brian yes I think that might be one of the main reasons alright